# Группировка кол-ва выполненных задач по сотрудникам

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Как сгруппировать корректно данные?

Имеется датафрейм со статусом завершенных заданий по каждому аналитику и типу задач:

```py
df1

    ID     Board   Analyst   Status   Crea_d       Fin_d
    46258  RUCRA   Ivanov    open     2019-07-10    NaT
    2345   RUCRA   Ivanov    close    2019-07-11   2019-07-11
    46218  RUCRA   Ivanov    close    2019-07-11   2019-07-11
    3087   RUCRA   Sidorov   open     2019-07-22    NaT
    2367   BV      Petrov    open     2019-07-25    NaT
    2985   GRADE   Petrov    close    2019-07-05   2019-07-05 
    20987  GRADE   Ivanov    close    2019-07-11   2019-07-12
    2396   BV      Sidorov   open     2019-07-29     NaT
```

Необходимо сгруппировать данные таким образом, чтобы было видно сколько аналитик выполнил и сколько еще невыполненных заданий по типам (Board) за определенный период (за день, неделю, месяц).

```py
grouped_df:

      Board   Analyst   Status   Count       
      RUCRA   Ivanov    open     1    
      RUCRA   Ivanov    close    2   
      RUCRA   Sidorov   open     1    
      BV      Petrov    open     1    
      GRADE   Petrov    close    1    
      GRADE   Ivanov    close    1
      BV      Sidorov   open     1
```

Я что-то похожее сделал, но где-то нарушена логика, где не могу разобраться:

```
grouped_df: = (df1.groupby(['Board','Analyst','Status', pd.Grouper(key='Fin_d', freq='M')], as_index=False)['ID'].count())
```

Просто дальше я хочу строить графики по каждому аналитику, сколько он по дням выполняет заданий (bars) с трендовой линией, но то ли из-за ошибки в коде или нарушения логики, ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
In [5]: df1.groupby(["Board", "Analyst", "Status"]).size().reset_index(name="Count")
Out[5]:
   Board  Analyst Status  Count
0     BV   Petrov   open      1
1     BV  Sidorov   open      1
2  GRADE   Ivanov  close      1
3  GRADE   Petrov  close      1
4  RUCRA   Ivanov  close      2
5  RUCRA   Ivanov   open      1
6  RUCRA  Sidorov   open      1
```

---

или так:

```
In [11]: df1.groupby(["Board", "Analyst", "Status", pd.Grouper(key='Crea_d', freq='MS')]).size().reset_index(name="Count")
Out[11]:
   Board  Analyst Status     Crea_d  Count
0     BV   Petrov   open 2019-07-01      1
1     BV  Sidorov   open 2019-07-01      1
2  GRADE   Ivanov  close 2019-07-01      1
3  GRADE   Petrov  close 2019-07-01      1
4  RUCRA   Ivanov  close 2019-07-01      2
5  RUCRA   Ivanov   open 2019-07-01      1
6  RUCRA  Sidorov   open 2019-07-01      1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, 2-й вариант просто самый идеальный - то что необходимо!